# SQL Select group where some attribute is same

Tags: sql

Lets say I have a table like this

```
A B C
-----
1 a 12
2 a 23
3 b 43
4 c 25
5 c 44
6 d 34
```

How to select only rows where B exists in another row?

Result would be:

```
A B C
-----
1 a 12
2 a 23
4 c 25
5 c 44
```

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? you are simply looking for how to find duplicate records :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.b = t.b and t2.a <> t.a
             );
```

With an index on `t(b, a)`, this is likely to be the fastest method.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are expecting but eliminating B & D

we can achieve like this

```
Select T.A,T.B,T.C from  Table T
INNER JOIN (
SELECT  B FROM Table
groUP by b
having count(B) > 1 )TT
ON T.B = TT.B
```